# Strange circles have appeared on QGIS map?

Tags: qgis

[image: Circles]

Why are circles appearing on my map? It started after using QGIS dev build 2.9 and now appears even on 2.8.1.

Also I've noticed that the usual list of CRS does not appear while using the dev build. Only custom CRSes appears. What gives?

The circles are not selectable or identifiable.

Circles seem to stay the same shape at different zoom labels.
[image]

Comment: There is not much information to go on I'm afraid. Does this happen in all projects or only one specific one? Could you share the project and data? Could you make a screencast showing the different layer properties?

Comment: Saving it as a shapefile causes the circles not to appear. Loading from the same postgresql db also doesn't show the circles. Looks like it might be caused by some other layers. Any tips to troubleshoot?

Comment: It only happens to this specific one

Comment: There was a posting on the UK QGIS Users group on Google+ about this problem recently. It has been reported as a bug, so it should be possible to find it on the bug-tracker.

Comment: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12618

Comment: ok. the problem disappears when I load the project as an 2.8.1 project. I guess there are some issues with the dev 2.9 project file

Comment: @seanlinmt could you explain how to load as a 2.8.1 project? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution that works for me from https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12618

> I had an old project that showed the circles after saving it QGIS 2.8.1. I wasn't using diagrams, but the diagram checkbox was checked after saving the project. Unchecking diagram mode fixed it for me.

For a project with many layers, you'll have to figure out which ones have had the Display Diagrams option turned on. Once you do, open the layer properties. Go to the Diagrams tab. The *Display Diagrams* check box is right at the top of the dialog box:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The problem originates from .qgs project files saved with 2.10.x and then opened in 2.8.1 or 2.8.2. These project files often contain an option to explicitly specify that there are **no** diagrams which is misinterpreted by QGIS <=2.8.2.

In 2.8.3 the problem has been solved, so the easiest way (apart from adapting the project file like outlined by @underdark's answer) is to **update your QGIS application to version 2.8.3** if you want to stay with LTR **or 2.10 or newer** if you don't care about LTR.

Update:
Time has moved on and **the current LTR version is 2.14**. There is not much reason to stick to 2.8 at all.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens even when a user never knew that "Diagrams" existed: the setting just turned itself on.