# Ubuntu 14.04 and QGIS 2.8.1 unmet dependency of libgdal .so.1-1.11.1

Tags: installation, ubuntu, qgis-2.8

I know that QGIS and unmet dependencies seem to be a common theme on this site, but this most recent one is a **known issue**. Through the standard Ubuntu updates in 14.04, at some point QGIS 2.8.1 has an unmet dependency with libgdal .so.1-1.11.1 and gets autoremoved. The solution on the [ubuntu-gis list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.osgeo.ubuntu/1027) is to upgrade to the nightly 2.9.x version.

However this is not without its problems: [Strange circles have appeared on QGIS map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143997/strange-circles-have-appeared-on-qgis-map) The circles appear for me in 2.9.x and I can't get them to go away.

There is currently no accepted answer to that question, so I wonder if there is some other way to install this vital package.

Comment: I had the same issue when I tried to install `python-gdal` last night. I didn't read what was going to be removed; it was `qgis`, `qgis-grass`, and `qgis-globe`. Then I couldn't re-install them (under `ubuntugis-unstable`), with this unmet dependency being cited as the issue. Overnight, the re-install no longer fails with this issue, and I haven't yet encountered any problems using 2.9.x. Are you using `ubuntugis-unstable`?

Comment: I was using `ubuntugis`. Trying `ubuntugis-unstable` now

Comment: I get a 404 error trying to update after adding the `ubuntugis` ppa, and same dependency error trying to install from `ubuntugis-unstable`.

Comment: The problem is due to two versions of libgdal: **libgdal1h** (default) and **libgdal**. The first one is installed with QGIS. If you want R with **rgdal** and **PostGis** you need **libgdal**. You can force to install libgdal to have rgdal and PostGis but your system will be broken without QGIS and uncapable to upgrade. My solution was to have stable Debian 8 in another partition. Everything works well there (However, I have one 15.04 version of Ubuntu because I am waiting for a definitive solution).

Comment: @xunilk I cannot understand what you are suggesting. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more searching I found @xunilk's answer on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/618307/334823

I removed the `ubuntugis` ppa and followed that answer and got 2.8.1 back.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. I experienced your unmet dependency with libgdal when I tried to install rgdal and Postgis. It was impossible for me to get a good installation. When I forced that (it is possible) I got a broken system uncapable to upgrade and without QGIS (autoremoved).